# CronJob Friendly PHP redirect

Tags: php, redirect, cron

I'm struggling with a PHP script that is activated by a Cronjob and includes a redirect.

The script finds records in my database, sends an email as appropriate and then redirects to a compiled URL so the details of the records can be imported into an external system.

The email part works fine via a Cronjob, the redirect does not, I understand that this is because Cronjobs do not operate within the browser but I'm not sure what is the best alternative method of redirecting to the URL.

Simplified code below:

```
<?php 

// Connect to DB
require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/admin/inc/dbconnect.php");

// Check DB for quotes that have not been sent to this client
$query_quotes = "SELECT * FROM quotes WHERE sent_client = 0 LIMIT 1";
$view_request = mysqli_query($GLOBALS['db_connect'], $query_quotes);

// Send to external system and email customer with quote
while ($quotes = mysqli_fetch_array($view_request)){

    $Body = "Email Content";

    // Send email via Swift Mailer

    // Send quote information to third party system via URL redirect
    header('Location: http://exampleurl/?FirstName='.rawurlencode($quotes['name']).'&businessName='.rawurlencode($quotes['company_name']).'.');

}

?>
```

Comment: You might have better luck with cURL http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php.

Comment: Can anybody help me with how to use cURL in this situation? I can make a simple cURL script work on the server but trying to replicate a redirect just seems to cause a timeout error, I presume because it's expecting a response that doesn't come?

Comment: I don't quite follow what you mean by a redirect? Judging from your example a simple HTTP request should suffice.

Answer (score 0):

It is as you said, you are not in a web-environment, so there is no browser to act on the `Location:` redirect. That doens't mean you can't pass information to a webpage - you just can't redirect to it - you call to it, and get information back - the info you get back might not be much - just 'OK, I got it' may well be more than enough. It might be as simple as

```
$url = "http://exampleurl/?FirstName=" . 
    rawurlencode($quotes['name']) . '&businessName=' .
    rawurlencode($quotes['company_name'])
$response = file_get_contents($url);
```

And the response might be as simple as `200 OK` (though if there is no response apart from just 'OK', officially according to the HTTP specs, you'd return `204 No Content`, but that is a very small thing).

Better still would be to use a proper HTTP calling function that dcan deal with potential issues like redirections and make life a little easier - something like the Guzzle library for example, but again, if file_get_contents works for you with a URL, that may be enough, at least while you are testing the basics.